# Match column values between two dataframes and obtain column name if true

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I have two data frames;

```
df1= {'col1': [9,2,2], 'col2': [5,1,0], 'col3': [9,3,2], 'col4': [8,3,2],  'col5': [6,0,0]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df1)

   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
0   9    5    9     8   6
1   2    1    3     3   0
2   2    0    2     2   0


df2 = [[9, 8], [3, 3], [2, 2]] 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2)
    0   1
0   9   8
1   3   3
2   2   2
```

I want to match the columns values, in this case, 9,3,2 and 8,3,2, and output the column names, in this case, 'col3' and 'col4'

I have tried:

`df2[0].value_counts() == df1['col3'].value_counts()`

and

`df1.values==df2.values` but not what I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `pd.DataFrame.eq`, `pd.DataFrame.all` and `pd.DataFrame.any`:

```
temp=df1.apply(lambda x: df2.eq(x,axis=0).all()).any()
temp.index[temp]
```

Output:

```
['col3', 'col4']
```

Comment: Exactly what I am after!